# Inserting values in master + child tables via Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 tables and for both primary keys are auto-generated.

```
public partial class Responses
{
        public Responses()
        {
            this.Answers = new HashSet<Answers>();
        }

        public int responseID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime create_dt { get; set; }                  
        public virtual ICollection<Answers> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

`responseID` is the autogenerated primary key

```
 public partial class Answers
 {
        public int answerID { get; set; }
        public int responseID { get; set; }
        public int questionID { get; set; }
        public string answer { get; set; }
        public virtual Questions Questions { get; set; }
        public virtual Responses Responses { get; set; }
 }
```

My effort to add RESPONSE and ANSWERS at the same time

```
public void addAnswers(List<Answers> an)
{
            Responses rp =new Responses();
            rp.create_dttm = DateTime.Today;
            db.Responses.Add(rp).Answers.Add(ans);
            db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I want to add answers at the same time as `Response` is inserted because `ResponseID` is autogenerated and I can't get the `ResponseID` to link it with `Answers` table. Please note that one `ResponseID` is associated with multiple questions.......

Thanks in advance

Comment: @marc_s could you please explain me as I am new to MVC and the attach function you suggested i have googled it but couldnt find a way to add master and sub entries at the same time

Comment: Your code seems OK, except the fact you don't use `Add` correctly. You should use a `foreach` loop to add each object `Answers` of the `ans` collection: `foreach (var answer in ans) { rp.Answers.Add(answer); }`.

Comment: Glad it works. :) For future references I'll add it as a dedicated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK, except the fact you don't use `Add` correctly. You should use a `foreach` loop to add each object `Answers` of the `ans` collection:

```
foreach (var answer in ans)
{
    rp.Answers.Add(answer);
}
```

Moreover you should respect naming conventions: you seem to use pluralization too often, e.g. probably `Responses` should be named `Response`, but I may be wrong, it all depends of the semantics of your entities...